# Number of non-strict, complete orderings

Tags: combinatorics

I am not great at combinatorics, and I recently faced the following question: Given a list of $n$ objects, how many non-strict, complete orderings are possible? The answer is obviously $n!$ for strict orderings, but I am thinking through the tie-portion.

I figured that with $3$ objects, there are $13$ possible options (easy to count); with $4$ there are $4!$ strict options, $3!\binom{4}{2}$ options with two objects tied and two strictly ranked, $\frac{2!\binom{4}{2}}{2}$ with two tied and two tied, $2!\binom{4}{3}$ with three tied and 1 strictly ranked, and $\binom{4}{4}$ way where everything is tied. So,

$$4! + 3!\binom{4}{2} + \frac{2!\binom{4}{2}}{2} + 2!\binom{4}{3} + \binom{4}{4} = 75
$$

possible complete, non-strict orderings with 4 objects. I'm having a hard time generalizing this to $n$ options though.